# Access Granted Through Sharing Rules is Inconsistent - Keep Having to Recalculate

Tags: security, sharing-rule, access

We're having a problem where we are continuously having to manually recalculate sharing rules in an org.

Account OWD is set to Private.

Sharing Rule 1: Account lookup field is populated by a certain record grants read/write access to Public Group 1.

Sharing Rule 2: Account Owner is in All Internal Users grants read/write access to Public Group 2.

Therefore, everyone in Public Group 2 should have Read/Write access to ALL Accounts, Contacts, Opportunities, Cases and all related Activities (because all Account Owners are in All Internal Users).

[image: Image shows the sharing granted for both Sharing Rules on Account]

Once every few weeks, a user puts in a ticket stating they can't see Tasks (related to Accounts) they don't own or they can't transfer a Task (related to an Account) to another user.

Recalculating the Account Sharing Rules always fixes this issue, but despite having a ticket open with Salesforce for almost two months now...we can't figure out why the problem is happening in the first place.

Any ideas what could be the root cause of this issue?

Comment: What does sf support say so far?

Comment: "You can edit or delete an activity when the following applies:
You have the “Edit Tasks” and “Edit Events” permissions
AND:
You’re assigned to the activity, or
You’re above the user assigned to the activity in the role hierarchy, or
You have the “Modify All” object-level permission in the related record, where the record’s sharing model is “Controlled By Parent.”
(with Shared Activities enabled, you need the “Modify All”
object-level permission for at least one contact and the related
record), or
You have the “Modify All Data” permission"

Comment: Their response doesn't make much sense to me, since the issue is temporarily resolved within moments of us recalculating the sharing rule.

Comment: Support can be useless unless you talk to Tier 3. Ask them to escalate the case.

Comment: I'll check to see what tier it's at. We've had it open for two months!

Comment: Just an update on this -- case is still open, escalated to Tier 3, and everyone is stumped. If anyone else is experiencing this issue, would love to try to collaborate on getting to the bottom of it!

Comment: Thanks for the update!

Comment: Another update -- case is STILL open with Tier 3 support at Salesforce, and no help. This is having a pretty major impact on a company with ~100 users. Has anyone ever experienced something similar?